# Don't show navbar on profile page - (Correct usage of current_page?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm currently working on a profile page app and I want to achieve that if someone visits a user on his profile (like domain.com/username) the navbar is not displayed. If a user is logged in, it can be visible.

I'm using Rails 4.2.0, Ruby 2.2.3 and Devise.

In my application.html.erb I have/tried

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
   <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>
<% else %>
   <%= render 'layouts/navbar' unless current_page?(controller: 'profiles', action: 'show')  %>
<% end %>
```

results in

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"devise/profiles"}
```

which is wrong because its calls the devise controller instead of the profile one (guess its something with my routes)

I also tried

```
<%= render 'layouts/navbar' unless current_page?(profiles_show_url) %>
```

which throws no error but still displays the nav bar on a user profile when not logged in.

So I just need to find a way to call the path, controller action, request.path or whatever to make this work, I guess it has something to do with my routes. I may also have my logic twisted here, probably a more elegant way to write this is available.

Thank you very much for your help!

**UPDATE:**

I now tried:

```
<% unless user_signed_in? or current_page?(profiles_show_path)%>
   <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>
<% end %>
```

When I used profile_path instead it works when I go to domain.com/username but as soon I go somewhere else it throws an error, because it wants to have the :user_name which is not passed when going to index for e.g.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"} missing required keys: [:user_name]
```

rake routes:

```
                    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
             profiles_show GET    /profiles/show(.:format)    profiles#show
          new_user_session GET    /login(.:format)            devise/sessions#new
              user_session POST   /login(.:format)            devise/sessions#create
      destroy_user_session DELETE /logout(.:format)           devise/sessions#destroy
             user_password POST   /password(.:format)         devise/passwords#create
         new_user_password GET    /password/new(.:format)     devise/passwords#new
        edit_user_password GET    /password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit
                           PATCH  /password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
                           PUT    /password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
  cancel_user_registration GET    /cancel(.:format)           registrations#cancel
         user_registration POST   /                           registrations#create
     new_user_registration GET    /sign_up(.:format)          registrations#new
    edit_user_registration GET    /edit(.:format)             registrations#edit
                           PATCH  /                           registrations#update
                           PUT    /                           registrations#update
                           DELETE /                           registrations#destroy
         user_confirmation POST   /confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#create
     new_user_confirmation GET    /confirmation/new(.:format) devise/confirmations#new
                           GET    /confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#show
                      root GET    /                           pages#index
                   profile GET    /:user_name(.:format)       profiles#show
              edit_profile GET    /:user_name/edit(.:format)  profiles#edit
            update_profile PATCH  /:user_name/edit(.:format)  profiles#update
                     posts GET    /posts(.:format)            posts#index
                           POST   /posts(.:format)            posts#create
                  new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)        posts#new
                 edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)   posts#edit
                      post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)        posts#show
                           PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)        posts#update
                           PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)        posts#update
                           DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)        posts#destroy
```

Comment: You are rendering same partial for both the cases `<%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>`

Comment: @Pavan thanks for your answer. yes, so the unless has no effect after that? I want to prevent that.

Comment: You can try this `current_page?(profile_path(current_user))` or `current_page?(controller: 'profiles', action: 'show', id: current_user.id)`

Comment: @AmitSharma when I use that, I get " missing required keys: [:user_name]" Maybe its not available when you are not logged in?

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the same action `profiles#show` routed two times in routes file.

Could you please try this,

Comment this line `get 'profiles/show'` in routes file. And use the following code,

```
 <% if user_signed_in? && !current_page?(profile_path(current_user.user_name))%>
    <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>
 <% elsif !current_page?(profile_path(params[:user_name])) %>
    <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>
 <% end %>
```

Above code expects `user_name` column in `users` table or corresponding devise associated model.

> And also make sure the `profile_path` is correctly used with the
>   `user_name` passed in all other places.

Note:- You could even move this logic to a helper method if it works (yn).

Comment: thanks. I did exactly what you said and I have user_name in the users table. When I go to domain.com/username the bar is gone but when I go somewhere else I get an exception 

    ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /
    No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles",     user_name=>nil} missing required keys: [:user_name]

Comment: Somewhere else means = index, static pages, login, etc etc. I will check your update. With this construct its logical that if I call index the user_name is nil and caused that exception, no? Profile path has that user_name passed.  get ':user_name', to: 'profiles#show', as: :profile

Comment: So profile_path needs a user_name, but that user name is not available when I'm going to the index path

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using

```
<% if user_signed_in? or controller.controller_name != "profiles" %>
    <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>  
<% end %>
```

which does what I need.